# php script require() statement fetches file when running from browser but not when running from Plesk CRON job

Tags: php, linux, cron, scheduled-tasks, plesk

I have a task script that works perfectly fine if i run it by visiting the php file from my browsers. However, when i attempt to run it via Plesk Task Scheduler it fail with a fatal error unable to load the `require()` file.

The require statement is a simple relative path:

`require('../../../app.config.php');`

the error is:

`PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../../../app.config.php'`

I think this may be related to the `include_path` but i don't know much about it so a bit lost on that one.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

relative pathes resolved by current directory. Solutions: Get script directory and combine with the relative path, something like:

```
 require(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../app.config.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use absolute path. A different relative path may be produced if a script is called directly or the script is included in another script.

For example:

```
a.php is on path A/B/C the ../../ will result in in A/
b.php is on path A/B/C/D, if it inlcudes the a.php then the ../../ on a.php will result in A/B/.
```